# Content of SwingNode not garbage collected when content changed

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a JavaFX application that displays a Swing plot via a SwingNode. Due to the way that the swing component is written and my unwillingness to refactor it, I create a new instance of the swing plot each time the user needs to update the data. In other words, whenever the user re-generates the plot, it creates a new Swing component and sets the SwingNode's content to the new component.

It all works fine except that I discovered that the swing components never get garbage collected. They contain a substantial amount of data, so after a while it becomes a pretty severe memory leak.

I've been able to demonstrate the issue with this minimum reproducible example:

```java
public class LeakDemo extends Application {

    //Keep week references to all panels that we've ever generated to see if any
    //of them get collected.
    private Collection<WeakReference<JPanel>> panels = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        
        SwingNode node = new SwingNode();
        
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(node);
        
        //Kick off a thread that repeatedly creates new JPanels and resets the swing node's content
        new Thread(() -> {
            
            while(true) {
                
                //Lets throw in a little sleep so we can read the output
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    panels.add(new WeakReference<>(panel));
                    node.setContent(panel);
                });
                
                System.out.println("Panels in memory: " + panels.stream().filter(ref -> ref.get() != null).count());
                
                //I know this doesn't guarantee anything, but prompting a GC gives me more confidence that this
                //truly is a bug.
                System.gc();
            }
            
        }).start();
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 100));
        
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The output of the program is

```
Panels in memory: 0
Panels in memory: 1
Panels in memory: 2
Panels in memory: 3
Panels in memory: 4
Panels in memory: 5
Panels in memory: 6
Panels in memory: 7
Panels in memory: 8
Panels in memory: 9
Panels in memory: 10
```

and will continue like that into the thousands.

I tried inspecting a heap dump from jvisualvm, but got pretty lost in the sea of references.

I'm suspicious that this is an issue in JavaFX, but I thought I'd check here before I report it as a bug.

Comment: If you remove the weakreference list and such, does the the memory leak still happen? If you just construct the panel and add the weak reference, do the references get cleared up?

Comment: Is the behavior still the same when you tell the container to update its references by calling `revalidate()`?

Comment: @Charlie yes, if I remove the WeakReference stuff, the leak still happens. Its just a little harder to demonstrate since I have to look at a heap dump in jvisualvm.

Comment: @Koenigsberg, none of the JavaFX components have a `revalidate()` method, but the swing components do. I tried getting the old SwingNode content and then calling `revalidate()` on it after replacing it with the new content and that didn't do the trick.

Comment: I've never debugged a memory leak in visualvm but (shockingly expensive) jprofiler is pretty useful. You could simply find all JPanels and trace back to the GC roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

## Short answer

Just wrap the swing content inside a `JPanel` (or some other `JComponent`). Then only ever call `SwingNode.setContent()` once to add the wrapper. When you need to update the swing content, call `removeAll()` on your wrapper and then `add()` with the appropriate content.

## Long Answer

Thanks to the suggestion in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66283491/2423283 I was able to determine that the leak is caused by `GlassStage` which is a non-api class which among other things, keeps a static list of all implementations of `GlassStage`. The content of a `SwingNode` gets managed by an instance of `EmbeddedScene` which is a subtype of `GlassStage`.

Items are removed from the static list when `close()` is called on them. `SwingNode.setContent()` does not close any pre-existing content, but `Container.removeAll()` does.

## Working code

Here's an example of the fixed code:

```
public class LeakDemoFixed extends Application {

    //Keep week references to all panels that we've ever generated to see if any
    //of them get collected.
    private Collection<WeakReference<JPanel>> panels = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        
        SwingNode node = new SwingNode();
        
        //These 2 lines were added
        JComponent swingContent = new JPanel();
        node.setContent(swingContent);
        
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(node);
        
        //Kick off a thread that repeatedly creates new JPanels and resets the swing node's content
        new Thread(() -> {
            
            while(true) {
                
                //Lets throw in a little sleep so we can read the output
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    panels.add(new WeakReference<>(panel));
                    //Removed the line below
                    //node.setContent(panel);
                    
                    //Added these 2 lines
                    swingContent.removeAll();
                    swingContent.add(panel);
                });
                
                System.out.println("Panels in memory: " + panels.stream().filter(ref -> ref.get() != null).count());
                
                //I know this doesn't guarantee anything, but prompting a GC gives me more confidence that this
                //truly is a bug.
                System.gc();
            }
            
        }).start();
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 100));
        
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice find! That might be worth filing a bug report with the JavaFX folks; at the very least, that behavior should be documented better in the setContent method.

Comment: I submitted a bug report. I'll post the link here for reference once it finishes the submit process. I'm a little doubtful that it will get much action though because there were a few similar bugs that were marked as resolved. I'm not sure if those other bugs really were resolved though because I think it may be the same issue. Guess we'll see.

Comment: Here's the bug report: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8262518

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: We finally moved JAVA8 and the issue persists for us using the latest JFX so I re-patched it, I need to perform a few verifications before trying to push it to JFX repo but if someone needs it it's here: https://github.com/ImKyra/jfx.git

---

I didn't reached this question before but here is what I've done to correct the issue. I would like this fix to be integrated into JavaFX for Java8 but I don't know how to get this done and they closed the issue (because of duplicate)

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8284352

The problem is due to the JLightweightFrame never being released by de SwingNodeDisposer.

The SwingNodeDisposer holds an hard pointer to the JLightweightFrame that prevents its suppression.

I have modified the SwingNode.setContentImpl() function to use a WeakReference instead of an hard pointer and now memory is properly released.

...

```
    WeakReference<JLightweightFrame> lwFramePtr = new WeakReference<JLightweightFrame>(lwFrame);
    SwingNodeDisposer disposeRec = new SwingNodeDisposer(lwFramePtr);
    Disposer.addRecord(this, disposeRec);
```

...

This gives good results without having the need to use a single JPanel or to encapsulate it inside a WeakReference.

Comment: hmm .. there has to be a very compelling reason (like f.i. security concerns) to get a fix backported. This site isn't the really a good place for bug fixes (workarounds are okay, but this doesn't feel like it, is it?) - You can try to drum up support at the openjfx dev mailing list

Comment: ohh, just seeing that the duplicate isn't yet fixed .. but already has a reference to this QA, so your solution will not get lost :)

Comment: Yeah problem is that this bug is critical to our application which is stuck in Java8 for various reasons. So i'm trying everything I can to get it integrated in an official release but one man can dream I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Take a snapshot with visualvm then analyze GC roots with with Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT) http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: Thanks for the great too recommendation. I've upvoted this since it definitely helped me figure out the issue. I didn't accept it as the answer though since its more of a debugging technique than an actual answer to the question.